# Merging/Joining Multiple Tables SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, join

I am working with a database that has 5 tables each with a different number of observations. I include a description of the columns in each table below. As you can see from below, Table 1,2 and 5 have SecurID in common, Table 3 and 4 have Factor in common, and lastly 3 and 5 have BID in common. I need to perform an anlysis of Table 1 vs 2's exposure and return by date. To do this I need to do mulitple merge/joins. I need to join tables 3 and 4 then join them with table 5 and lastly with 1 and 2. What I tried was multiple joins like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table3
INNER JOIN Table4 ON Table3.Factor = Table4.Factor
LEFT JOIN Table5 ON Table3.BID = Table5.BID
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table5.SecurID = Table1.SecurID
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table5.SecurID = Table2.SecurID
```

My problem is that when I run this query I get a crazy amount of extra observations. Are multiple join functions the most efficient way to combine all these tables? I'm very new to SQL, but each table has an index, which I believe is a faster way to speed up the data retrieval process compared with SELECT.

- Table 1 (32,800 Observ.): SecurID, HoldingDate, Weight
- Table 2 (2200 Observ.): SecurID, HoldingDate, Weight
- Table 3 (808400 Observ.): BID, Factor, Exposure, Date
- Table 4 (8000 Observ.): Factor, Return, FactorGrpName
- Table 5 (1600 Observ.): SecurID, SecurName, BID

Comment: What are you using outer joins?  From what you describe, `inner join` should be sufficient.

Comment: LEFT JOIN combined with RIGHT JOIN?!?

Comment: I tried using all inner joins, and the query is still running, but I'm at 2 million results and counting.

Comment: You are probably producing a huge amount of rows since you are combining all tables, and the query does not have any filtering condition. Do you really want all rows from all tables, or just some region, date range, etc?

Comment: Please provide a minimal sample data and expected results. A few rows will go a long way to understand what you want.

Comment: I dont need all the rows from all tables. I only need the observations that, when all tables are merged, go with the merged data for Table 1 and Table 2. @TheImpaler

Comment: @TheImpaler I believe I found the problem, but do not know how to resolve the problem. When I join the data, I am joing tables with 3 different dates: datadate, datadate and holding date. All 3 of these dates are different, in the same row, when i execute the join function. Example: Column1,2,3,4,5,6 are: Barrid, Datadate, HoldingDate, DataDate, Factor and Exposure. A result (row) for the column order respectively: BRAAB, 2016/05/31, 2016/08/31,2018/11,GEMLTL, -1.29

Comment: One reason you might be experiencing an explosion of records is the fields you're joining on might match multiple records. For example, if 2 tables are joined on Factor and each has 10 rows where Factor = 10, you'll get 100 rows in your result. An easy test to see if this is an issue is a query like the following and see if you have duplicates SELECT TOP 100 SecurID FROM Table1 GROUP BY SecurID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: @RobertSheahan you are right, that is the problem, but is there a specific function I can use to avoid this problem?

Comment: There are a number of ways, typically you would either add extra conditions to your JOIN or aggregate one of the tables before joining, can you tell us more about your data? Are there fields you've left out that might help distinguish records? Which fields have multiples? What do the values mean? Post this in the original question so others can see it, we're far enough down the comments that it will get lost if you post it in a comment.